# Need help animating two things with a background in turtle python

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I have both the drawings under `guy0` and `guy1`, and the background is `back0`. I can have one of the drawings animate with the method I am trying to use, but not both.

I also cannot seem to get the background to be drawn when I animate it either. The other human is the exact same as the `human0` just a different color shirt. I needed to make this post shorter. Any help is appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
from turtle import *
def back0():
  delay(0)
  tracer(0)
  bgcolor("#87ceeb")
  up()
  goto(0,0)
  pd()
  up()
  goto(160,350)
  pd()
  fillcolor("#FDB813")
  begin_fill()
  circle(60)
  end_fill()
  rt(90)
  up()
  fd(5)
  rt(90)
  pd()
  begin_fill()
  fd(5)
  lt(130)
  fd(20)
  lt(130)
  fd(20)
  lt(30)
  lt(90)
  fd(15)
  end_fill()
  up()

def guy0(x,y):
  delay(0)
  tracer(0)
  up()
  goto(x,y)
  pd()
  fillcolor("#E8BEAC")
  begin_fill()
  circle(25)
  end_fill()
  up()
  goto(x,y-80)
  pd()
  fd(20)
  lt(90)
  fd(60)
  fillcolor("#FF5F1F")
  begin_fill()
  circle(20,180)
  end_fill()
  begin_fill()
  fd(60)
  lt(90)
  fd(40)
  lt(90)
  fd(60)
  lt(90)
  up()
  fd(40)
  end_fill()
  setheading(0)

xCoor = -400
yCoor = -50
screen = Screen()
def move():
  global xCoor, yCoor
  xCoor += 3
  

  if xCoor  > 420:
    xCoor=-420
  
  clear()
  guy0(xCoor,yCoor)

  screen.ontimer(move,1)

move()
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see `guy1` or `human0` anywhere, so I'll work with your code as-is and let you take it from there.

In general, when debugging and coding, it's important to work slowly and methodically. If you leap ahead and add a bunch of code without validating that it makes sense and works at each step along the way, you can easily wind up with 4-5 problems that are hard to fix.

- `back0` is never called.
- `tracer(0)` and `bgcolor("#87ceeb")` should be one-off calls at the beginning of the program rather than running in the loop, doing the same thing over and over.
- I'm not sure what your screen size is, but for me, `goto(160,350)` moves what appears to be the sun offscreen and there are some `pd()`/`up()` calls that don't seem to achieve anything. I'd add a comment or move the sun-drawing code into its own function so it's easier to understand.
- After drawing the sun, call `setheading(0)` to restore the heading and avoid `guy0`'s body from being drawn askew.
- I suggest `screen.ontimer(10)`, the default value, rather than `screen.ontimer(1)`, which is faster than my screen can refresh and might result in jitter.

Here are the modifications with comments:

```py
from turtle import *

def back0():
    up()
    goto(0, 0)
    goto(160, 150) # 350 is off-screen for me
    pd()
    fillcolor("#FDB813")
    begin_fill()
    circle(60)
    end_fill()
    rt(90)
    up()
    fd(5)
    rt(90)
    pd()
    begin_fill()
    fd(5)
    lt(130)
    fd(20)
    lt(130)
    fd(20)
    lt(30)
    lt(90)
    fd(15)
    end_fill()
    up()
    setheading(0) # restore heading

def guy0(x, y):
    up()
    goto(x, y)
    pd()
    fillcolor("#E8BEAC")
    begin_fill()
    circle(25)
    end_fill()
    up()
    goto(x, y - 80)
    pd()
    fd(20)
    lt(90)
    fd(60)
    fillcolor("#FF5F1F")
    begin_fill()
    circle(20, 180)
    end_fill()
    begin_fill()
    fd(60)
    lt(90)
    fd(40)
    lt(90)
    fd(60)
    lt(90)
    up()
    fd(40)
    end_fill()
    setheading(0)

x_coor = -400
y_coor = -50
screen = Screen()
ht()               #
tracer(0)          # call once up front rather than in the loop
bgcolor("#87ceeb") #

def move():
    global x_coor, y_coor
    x_coor += 3

    if x_coor > 420:
        x_coor =- 420

    clear()
    back0()
    guy0(x_coor, y_coor)
    screen.ontimer(move, 10)

move()
exitonclick()
```

Now, if you want to animate another person, add coordinates and a draw function and call it in the loop just like `guy0`. Or research and create a class (and probably also lists and loops) which can be used to store coordinates dynamically to let you make as many people as you want easily, without repeating the code with `guy0`, `guy1`... `guy100` which gets tedious quickly.

Consider also using `from turtle import Screen, Turtle`, or at least itemizing all imported variables rather than using a wildcard. This keeps your variables clearly separated from turtle, avoiding aliasing bugs, and helps prevent bugs caused by using both the functional and instance modes at the same time.